# Creating an online form with intergrated google maps

Tags: kml, google

I am looking at creating an online form that includes a map (google or something similar) where the user can draw a poly and when the user hits submit, i get all the info plus a shapefile or kmz  of the area drawn, have been looking for various solutions to this and not getting very far.

Answer (score 1):

This is a link to Google's documentation on how to allow users to draw polygons and other shapes on a map:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer

The basic steps are:

1. Add a drawing tool to the map.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools

2. Add a listener event for when the user completes the shape:

When a shape overlay is created, two events are fired:
 •An {overlay}complete event (where {overlay} represents the overlay type, such as circlecomplete, polygoncomplete, etc). A reference to the overlay is passed as an argument.
 •An overlaycomplete event. An object literal, containing the OverlayType and a reference to the overlay, is passed as an argument.

3. Get the coordinates of the polygon.

Here's a code example from another stackoverflow answer on how to get the coordinates of the polygon:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function (polygon) {
    var coordinates = (polygon.getPath().getArray());
    console.log(coordinates);
  });
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407451/how-to-get-point-coordinates-of-a-modified-drawingmanager-shape-googlemaps-api

The Google Maps API reference documentation can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference